# Error opening a VCD with VLC (VideoLan) player

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, vcd

There have been a couple of questions on playing VCDs in Linux, like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/93408/playing-vcd-dat-in-linux) - but many years have passed since then.

I'm trying to play a VCD on Devuan 3 Beowulf (~= Debian 10 Buster without systemd). I can mount the disk; but MPV won't recognize it, and if I try "Open Disc" using VLC (the VideoLan player), I get the error message:

> Your input can't be opened:
>   VLC is unable to open the MRL 'vcd:///media/cdrom0'. Check the log for details.

I don't know why it's failing, plus - since when does VLC have a log?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the device file, not the device's mount point.

Well, I figured out at least why it's failing:

VLC expects you to specify a *device* on which to look for a VCD, not a folder with files in it (although why that's the case is beyond me.) In Linux, devices are specified by a pair of numbers (major, minor); but there are filesystem nodes associated with these numbers, creating a mapping of file paths to devices.

So, in a terminal, run:

```
$ df /media/cdrom
```

and you should get something like:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sr0          563718 563718         0 100% /media/cdrom0
```

the `/dev/sr0` string is what VLC expects.